# How to close the Drawer while keeping the Dialog opened?

Tags: flutter

**Minimal code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainPage()));

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Close the Drawer, not the Dialog. 
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop());

          // Show the Dialog and keep it in opened state. 
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(title: Text('FooDialog')),
          );
        },
        child: Text('Show Dialog'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On pressing the button, I am showing dialog and after 2s I want to close the `Drawer` while keeping the `Dialog` opened on the screen. For this I am using `Timer` and `rootNavigator` property of `Navigator`. However, my dialog is getting dismissed.

Is there any solution for closing the drawer besides using `GlobalKey<DrawerControllerState>` stuff?

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Close the Drawer, not the Dialog. 
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer());

          // Show the Dialog and keep it in opened state. 
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(title: Text('FooDialog')),
          );
        },
       child: Text('Show Dialog'),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ScaffoldState`, to close the drawer. Just keep a track of the time and you are good to go. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884448/5362583) answer, I have told you on how to use the `ScaffoldState` with your drawer.

This code will help you achieve what you want. I have used the second option from my previous answer, that is, using everything in the `MainPage` only

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  
  // this will check for the drawer state and close it
  // using _scaffoldKey
  timer() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      // checking whether it is open
      if(_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen){
        // here how you close it
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
      }
    });
  }
  
  Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
                Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Approve'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
  
  // Our drawer
  Drawer _drawer(BuildContext context) => Drawer(
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: (){
        timer();
        _showMyDialog(context);
      },
      child: Text('Show Dialog'),
    )
  );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: _drawer(context)
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Resultant GIF]

**Please note:** I have not clicked anywhere on the screen, to close the drawer. It goes automatically by the `timer()`

Comment: Thanks Alok, I already knew the `ScaffoldState` part, didn't want to use that.

Comment: Can you tell me why `rootNavigator` isn't doing its work in my code. It should have popped the root navigator, which was for `Drawer` right?

Comment: Not sure @iLoveDocs I don't want give you any false information. However, using this would definitely be a nice workaround, without affecting your view much :) Although, what I can think of for now is, using opening up a drawer isn't a part of the `NavigationRouter`, hence the machine is not able to get any thing. When page transition happens, it adds the pages to the stack. That is what I believe is the case :0

Comment: Your solution is good as long as I am using it in the same class. I have separate classes for `MainPage` and `Drawer` (and other deep nested widgets), and in order to use the GlobalKey part, I'll either have to make it global or pass it to the Drawer, which I don't personally like for a very small task.

Comment: Well, if you don't find one, then using the `Globals` concept, is what will resolve the issue. So, your call @iLoveDocs

Comment: Well your answer is also a workaround because you're trying to open the end drawer to close the regular drawer. alecsam answer is much more cleaner in that way.