# How to use DrawerControllerState in a Drawer?

Tags: flutter

**Minimal code:**

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainPage()));

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  final _drawerKey = GlobalKey<DrawerControllerState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      key: _drawerKey,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => print(_drawerKey.currentState), // Prints null
        child: Text('Show Dialog'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I press the button, it prints `null`, so what's the correct way of using the `DrawerControllerState`?

Comment: Why do you want to use it, that is the I should ask?

Comment: @Alok I want to close the `Drawer` in the `MainPage` class itself.

Comment: That means with the press of the button it should close itself, right?

Comment: @Alok Not exactly like that, here's my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883223/how-to-close-the-drawer-while-keeping-the-dialog-opened) explaining my needs of using `DrawerControllerState`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close the Drawer while keeping the Dialog opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883223/how-to-close-the-drawer-while-keeping-the-dialog-opened)

Comment: @evan Hi, both the questions belong to the same account.

Answer (score 0):

See, the problem is, you are not using your `key` correctly. Firstly, in order to get the state of the `Drawer`, you need to have `ScaffoldState` not the `DrawerControllerState` type key.

With the use of `ScaffoldState.currentState`, you will be getting the data. Also, if you want to see whether your drawer is open or closed. You can use it like this:

```
ScaffoldState.currentState.isDrawerOpen
```

There are two ways to do this:

**1. Declaring the GlobalKey gloabally for accessing it anywhere**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainPage()));

// declare it globally or make your drawer inside the MainPage only
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey, // <-- Use your key here not for drawer
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => print(_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen), // <-- prints true, when open
        child: Text('Show Dialog'),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**2. Make your drawer inside your MainPage only. Easily accessible**

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  
  Drawer get _drawer => Drawer(
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => print(_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen), // <-- prints true when opened
      child: Text('Show Dialog'),
    )
  );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey, // <-- Using Key for Scaffold
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: _drawer
    );
  }
}
```

Passing the `GlobalKey` from `MainPage` to `MyDrawer` won't help. You can play with that.

Comment: Thank you so much but that didn't answer my question.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884731/5362583) @iLoveDocs